# WHERE IN (SELECT NonExistingColumnName) causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I recently had a situation where I needed to delete some rows from a table and mis-spelt a column name.
There was no error thrown and ALL the rows were deleted from the table.
Here is a script that reproduces the issue.

There is an Order table with four orders with OrderID.
There is a LIST_TO_DELETE table with one ItemID.

I should have used

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Orders WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM #LIST_TO_DELETE  )
```

instead I used

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Orders WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM #LIST_TO_DELETE  )
```

This caused all rows in the #Orders table to be deleted when I only meant to delete one.

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders (OrderID INT, OrderName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Orders(OrderID, OrderName) VALUES (1,'Order One'),(2,'Order Two'),(3,'Order Three'), (4,'Order Four')

CREATE TABLE #LIST_TO_DELETE (ItemID INT);INSERT INTO #LIST_TO_DELETE(ItemID) VALUES (1)

DECLARE @rowcount INT = 1
WHILE @rowcount > 0 
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Orders WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM #LIST_TO_DELETE  )
    SET @rowcount = @@rowcount
END 

SELECT * FROM #Orders

DROP TABLE #Orders
DROP TABLE #LIST_TO_DELETE
```

In my original code, the Orders table was real and LIST_TO_DELETE was a table variable but it seems to make no difference what table type is used.
If I use any column name apart from OrderID or ItemID, I get an error

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Orders WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OtherID FROM #LIST_TO_DELETE  )
 Invalid column name 'OtherID'
```

Why did this code behave this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the article to understand what is happening: [Qualifying Column Names in Subqueries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050(v=sql.105).aspx)

> The general rule is that column names in a statement are implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause at the same level. If a column does not exist in the table referenced in the FROM clause of a subquery, it is implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause of the outer query.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue.

The following statement will erroneously `delete` **ALL** the rows from the users table:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM groups);
```

even if the groups table does not have a column named user_id.

The following statement will, however, throw an error:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id IN (SELECT g.user_id FROM groups g);

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name user_id
```

EDIT

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Orders WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OtherID FROM #LIST_TO_DELETE  )
 Invalid column name 'OtherID'
```

This throws an error, because `OtherID` doesn't exist in `#Orders`

Comment: I don't believe I've encountered that, but seems to me that without the alias, SQL Server thinks the user id comes from the users table. an easy test would be to use a column name that doesn't exist in either table and see what happens.

Comment: That will throw an error. You are right about SQL assuming that user_id comes from users table

Comment: @Raj Do you have a link to an MSDN or any Microsoft page where this issue is described?

Comment: Why does it assume that OrderID comes from the Orders table when the code clearly states that we want the OrderID from LIST_TO_DELETE table.
I understand that if I was using a join or the same table twice that a table alias might be needed.
Does SQL convert "WHERE IN" to a "JOIN" in the background?

Comment: because it is possible to use fields from your outer query in your subquery. Like delete from users where userid in (select userid from groups where groups.somefield = users.somefield). This delete makes no sense i know it is just to demonstrate that fields from outer select can be used here)

Comment: I don't have any link to MSDN, but learnt about this behaviour from a coding standards document for a project I worked on more than a decade back. Ideally, when not qualified, the inner query is treated like a correlated subquery