# Why does this SQL code behave this why. Shouldn't a compile error throw?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Examine this SQL problem. Very interesting why the SQL compiles. The last select statement should throw and error as the column client_id does not exist in the temp table. It seems to be using the scope of the first table client_orders. But even so, once resolved, it always resolves to TRUE when evaluating the IN statement. Below is some code.

This is just a puzzle. I have explorer what happens when the statement in IN is null or invalid and it just picks up as a compile error. It seems like there is confusion with use client_id.

Here is the example.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('client_order') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE client_order
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#to_delete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #to_delete
GO

CREATE TABLE client_order
(
       client_id INT NOT NULL,
       order_id INT NOT NULL,
       order_data CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{"amount":12}'
)
GO

INSERT INTO client_order (client_id, order_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 1)

SELECT * FROM client_order

CREATE TABLE #to_delete
(
       bobo INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #to_delete VALUES (1),(3)

SELECT * FROM client_order
WHERE client_id IN (SELECT client_id FROM #to_delete)
```

- WTF? Why did all records get returned?!
- I know that the select in #to_delete uses the incorrect column, but why wasn't this caught as an error
- Further more, why would that select statement always return true when checking if client_id is IN that statement?

The client_id values of 2 should still remain. Why don't they?

Comment: The attribute you refer to in the IN query is first searched within that query, if it id not found there, it is searched for in the outer query (ie client_order). To correct this you should use table aliases.

Comment: Don't omit table / table alias when referencing a column.

Comment: [No, this is not a bug in T-SQL](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2019/04/23/no-this-is-not-a-bug-in-t-sql/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE IN (SELECT NonExistingColumnName) causes unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091069/where-in-select-nonexistingcolumnname-causes-unexpected-behaviour)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your table `#to_delete` does not have a column called `client_id`.  So, you think you have written:

```
SELECT co.*
FROM client_order co
WHERE co.client_id IN (SELECT d.client_id FROM #to_delete d);
```

But this would generate a column unknown error.  So, this is interpreted as:

```
SELECT co.*
FROM client_order co
WHERE co.client_id IN (SELECT co.client_id FROM #to_delete d);
```

And everything is returned.

Lesson:  **Always qualify all column references in a query.**  If you include the table alias with the column name, you will never have this problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It was deliberate that I added the column name that is not in the to_delete schema. But why was everything returned? This is the part that confuses me.

Comment: @GrantWilson . . . Because you are comparing `co.client_id` to `co.client_id`.  They are always equal (assuming the value is never `NULL`).

Comment: Thank you for responding to this. :)